# Отправить письмо на Delphi на платформе Windows 7

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Вот написал программу по скрытой отправке е-mail, но письмо отправляется только с windows XP! А у меня Windows 7. Появляется ошибка, что делать? Вот код:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdSMTP1.Host:= 'smtp.mail.ru' ; //адрес smtp-сервера
  IdSMTP1.Port:=25;
  IdSMTP1.Username:='логин';
  idSMTP1.Password:='пароль';
  idMessage1.Body.Text:='Тест письмо';
  idMessage1.From.Text:='xxx@mail.ru';
  idMessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses:='yyy@mail.ru';
  idMessage1.Subject:='Тема';
  idSMTP1.Connect();
  if idSMTP1.Connected=true then
  begin
    idSMTP1.Send(idMessage1);
    idSMTP1.Disconnect;
  end
else //Нет соединения!!!
end;
```

Comment: что за ошибка появляется?
так просто к сведенью if idSMTP1.Connected=true then тоже самое что и if idSMTP1.Connected then... 

попробуйте перед данной проверкой поставить sleep(10000);

Comment: Код работает! НО только на Windows XP.

Comment: Вот такая ОШИБКА появляется: Syntactically invalid EHLO argument(s);

Comment: [Гуглите хоть иногда](http://www.nobat.ru/q/the-bat-faq/problema-syntactically-invalid-helo-argument-s-151/)...

Comment: ToRcH2565 ну и что вы мне дали!? Конкретно для моей проблемы там нет решения, ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ?!

Comment: Все всем спасибо, кто хотел помочь (особенно ToRcH2565)! Ошибка исправленна!

Comment: @NIXON_NB, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, примите его. Если вы сами нашли ответ, дайте ответ (это избавит всех от повторных вопросов).

Answer (score 2):

```
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
     begin
       idsmtp1.Host:='smtp.yandex.ru' ;// хост
     idsmtp1.MailAgent:='Mozilla';// имя агента
    idsmtp1.Port:=25 ;// порт
    idsmtp1.Username:='login' ;// логин почты
    idsmtp1.Password:='******' ;// пароль почты
    idmessage1.CharSet:='windows-1251';// кодировка (русские символы)
    idmessage1.ContentType:='text/plain'; // тип письма 
    idmessage1.Body.Add(memo1.text) ;// текст письма
    idmessage1.Subject:=AnsiString('Привет.');// тема письма
    idmessage1.From.text:= 'xxx@yandex.ru';// от кого
    idmessage1.Recipients.EMailAddresses:='yyy@yandex.ru';// кому
    idmessage1.IsEncoded:=true;

      try
      try
       idsmtp1.connect; // соединяемся
       idsmtp1.Send(idmessage1);// отправляем
       ShowMessage('Письмо отправлено!');// ура получилось
      except on E:Exception do
       begin

        ShowMessage('Письмо не отправлено!');// не получилось
       end;
      end;
     finally
      if idsmtp1.Connected // проверяем соединение
      then idsmtp1.Disconnect; // разъединяем
     end;
     end;// конец
Код работает под Windows 7.
Совет: Обнови инди компоненты.
```

Comment: Добрый день, попробовал данный код, выскакивает ошибка: 

>`prohect P_test raised exeption class EldSocket Error with message 'Socket Error #10060 Connection timed out.'.Process stoped`

Подскажите, плз, как это исправить. Брандмаузер выключен, антивирус тоже, порт открыт, e-mail указал существующие.